# Passing generic object in c# class contructor

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm creating class that inherit from Base class but I have problem with passing generic argument to constructor in based class. Is it possible to do this without making base class generic?

Below example is not working because `Options<FileDataSource> cannot be converted to Options<DataSource>`.

```cs
interface DataSource
    {

    }

    interface FileDataSource : DataSource
    {

    }

    class BaseOptions : Options<DataSource>
    {

    }

    class Options<T> where T : DataSource
    {

    }

    class BaseClass
    {
        public BaseClass(Options<DataSource> baseOptions)
        {

        }
    }

    class FileClass : BaseClass
    {
        public FileClass(Options<FileDataSource> baseOptions) : base(baseOptions)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: **but I have problem** what is your problem extectly?

Comment: it doesn't compile; explain why.

Comment: In the future, include the error message:  `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Options<FileDataSource>' to 'Options<DataSource>'`

Comment: The problem most likely is that you want to use covariance, but concrete classes like `Options<T>` do not support it.  Try specifying `IOptions<T>` in the constructor instead (assuming the interface exists).